# How to correctly access nested aliases with sass/node-sass in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, node-sass

I am trying to break my scss partials into multiple files and aggregate it into one file and access variables accordingly. I have this folder structure:

```
create-react-app/src  
│
└───Styles
│   │
│   └───Tokens
│   |   │ _Colors.scss
│   |   │ _Tokens.scss
│   | _Base.scss
```

Inside `_Colors.scss`, I have a simple variable: `$primary-color: red;`.

```scss
// _Colors.scss

$primary-color: red;
```

Inside `_Tokens.scss` I use the `@use` rule to import my partial and give it an alias: `@use "./Colors.scss" as colors;`.

```scss
// _Tokens.scss

@use "./Colors" as colors;
```

In my `_Base.scss` I am importing my `Tokens.scss` and giving that an alias as well: `@use "Styles/Tokens/Tokens" as tokens;`. I then try to access the nested alias/namespace, eg:

```scss
// _Base.scss

@use "Styles/Tokens/Tokens" as tokens;

body {
  color: tokens.colors.$primary-color; // Linter has an issue with .colors
}
```

I am confronted with a linter error: `identifier or variable expectedscss(css-idorvarexpected).` React also spits out an error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected "(".
   ╷
10 │   color: tokens.colors.$primary-color;
   │                       ^
```

Confused on what to do at this point, I've tried for a few hours poking around Google but can't find anything. Help would be appreciated, thank you! Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: issue is case which you used as alias,  it should be @use "Styles/Tokens/Tokens" as tokens;  tokens in lowercase to work properly

Comment: @Naga Sai A I do have it as lowercase in the code; I typed it wrong in the question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with the `@forward` syntax.

From the docs:
"The @forward rule loads a Sass stylesheet and makes its mixins, functions, and variables available when your stylesheet is loaded with the @use rule. It makes it possible to organize Sass libraries across many files, while allowing their users to load a single entrypoint file."

This allows you to import a single file, eg. _tokens.scss, rather than importing multiple files.

For example, we have a directory called tokens/. Inside tokens/, we have multiple different partial files to hold many different variables, based off their category (eg. colors, fonts). Lastly, we have a single _tokens.scss partial file which we will use to "forward" all of our separate partial files so that we only need to import *one* partial, instead of every single partial file.

Take a look at this example:

```
tokens/
  _colors.scss
  _fonts.scss
  _tokens.scss
```

Inside `_colors.scss`:

```scss
$brand: rebeccapurple;
```

Now, we can forward this in our `_tokens.scss` and namespace it as needed:

```
// _tokens.scss

// we namespace our variables inside _colors.scss as colors-* meaning we need to prefix our variable names inside _colors.scss as $colors-VARIABLE, in this case $colors-brand

@forward "./colors" as colors-*;
```

Now, we only need to call `_tokens.scss` in any sass file that may need our tokens. Let's say we have a `_sections.scss` partial file that holds our section components:

```scss
// _sections.scss
@use "path/to/tokens" as tokens; // namespaced as tokens

// we can call our $brand variable inside _colors.scss as follows:

.section-about {
  // notice the "$colors-" prefix. This is how I namespaced it in _tokens.scss.
  color: tokens.$colors-brand; 
}
```

See: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/forward

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing "Tokens" in `@use "Styles/Tokens/Tokens" as Tokens;` lowercase? Because you have it lowercase in the scss below it, `color: tokens.colors.$primary-color;`

Comment: I have, sorry it was a typo in my question. I changed it to lowercase in my question to reflect what I have in the code.